# Views and HTTPresponse with user's data - Django

Tags: python, django, http

Given a GET the url is /home/data

Where data is a value that will depend on the user, that is, the complete domain will be

domain/home/data

What I want is to return an HTTP response depending on the data value

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', home, name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
def home (request):
    response =item.objects.filter(radius<data)
    return HttpResponse(response )
```

As you can see, radius is an attribute of the item model. And I want to filter all radius that are less than data.

How can I include data in that home function?

Answer (score 2):

The `path` should then look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/<int:data>/', home, name='home'),
]
```

such that it thus includes `data` as an `int`: You can then filter with the [**`__lt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt):

```
def home(request, data):
    # …
    response = item.objects.filter(radius__lt=data)
    # …
```

Of course here `data` needs to come from somewhere. You can not directly put `item` objects in a `HttpResponse`, a HTTP response is a stream of bytes. You can for example JSON serialize the data, or do some other encoding, but you can not use `item`s in your response. You can for example use:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import JsonResponse
from json import loads


def home(request, data):
    response = item.objects.filter(radius__lt=data)
    data = serialize('json', response)
    return JsonRespnse({'data': loads(data)})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would capture it from the URL like this

```
path('home/<data>/', home, name='home'),
```

You can get it in the view with

```
def home(request, data=None):
```